# Output line number of running python program

Tags: python, instrumentation

Is there a way to output line number of python program when running?

e.g., given the following program

```
if False: #line 1
    print("hello") #line 2
else: #line 3
    print("hello1")#line 4
```

It will output 1,3,4 after execution of the program.

Comment: I'm thinking `pdb` tracing, but I could be wrong

Comment: I think I get the question and have the same one. See his #line 2 comment? How can you find that line number in a running program. I personally want to print("line number", get.lineNumber()) 

not a real function but I hope you get the idea. As I build my program the line moves making the print statement wrong with a static number typed there.

Comment: This should not be closed and the answer link given is wrong.

import inspect

def lineno():
    """Returns the current line number in our program."""
    return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question, but I think this'll answer it.

Try checking out this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

And go down to section 26.7.1.1.
I believe that the `-c --count` command is what you're looking for, or the `-t --trace`.